# How to use UIDVALIDITY and HIGHESTMODSEQ of an imap folder to sync email

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, imap

I want to sync emails locally from an imap server using java mail. I read RFC-4551 and RFC-4549, but still not clear about the algorithm to sync mails. Basically I am not sure how to use UIDVALIDITY in conjugation with HIGHESTMODSEQ of a folder to sync emails from server. Can someone please clarify the algorithm for syncing mails if

1. The server support CONDSTORE
2. The server does not support CONDSTORE

Comment: an IMAP sync algorithm is actually quite complex, and depends on what your use case actually is.

Comment: uidValidity + uidNext may be what you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

A complete answer to this question is much longer than is appropriate for stackoverflow.  Maybe you can tell us what you **think** the algorithm is, and we can help you figure out if you got it right?

I can clarify UIDVALIDITY...  UIDVALIDITY tells you if the folder is the same folder you looked at previously, or if it's a completely different folder that just happens to have the same name.  If the folder is deleted and a new folder is created with the same name, the UIDVALIDITY will change.  The UIDs of messages in the folder are all relative to the UIDVALIDITY of the folder.  If the UIDVALIDITY of a folder changes, throw away all cached data for the folder.